# volttron troubleshoot rpc call get_point

Tags: volttron

Any chance for a tip on how to troubleshoot a simple `get_point` rpc call to a BACnet device? Something I am doing on the rpc call throws this error: `'DriverAgent\' object has no attribute \'interface\'`

This is my device:
`vctl config get platform.driver registry_configs/33333.csv`

That prints:

```
[
  {
    "Reference Point Name": "signal_payload",
    "Volttron Point Name": "signal_payload",
    "Units": "percent",
    "Unit Details": "(default 0.0)",
    "BACnet Object Type": "analogValue",
    "Property": "presentValue",
    "Writable": "FALSE",
    "Index": "0",
    "Write Priority": "",
    "Notes": "Open ADR Payload Signal"
  },
  {
    "Reference Point Name": "int_signal_duration",
    "Volttron Point Name": "int_signal_duration",
    "Units": "percent",
    "Unit Details": "(default 0.0)",
    "BACnet Object Type": "analogValue",
    "Property": "presentValue",
    "Writable": "FALSE",
    "Index": "1",
    "Write Priority": "",
    "Notes": "Integer Signal Duration"
  }
]
```

device address:
`vctl config get platform.driver devices/slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/33333`
this will print:

```
{
  "driver_config": {
    "device_address": "10.200.200.224",
    "device_id": 33333
  },
  "driver_type": "bacnet",
  "registry_config": "config://registry_configs/33333.csv"
}
```

I think I have something wrong in my agent code in the `dr_level = self.vip.rpc.call` as shown in the snip below as the code errors out right after the `ACTUATOR AGENT SCHEDULE SUCCESS`:

```
dr_status = self.vip.rpc.call(
    'platform.actuator', 'request_new_schedule', self.agent_id, 'my_test', 'HIGH', schedule_bac0_request).get(
    timeout=4)

_log.info(f'*** [Setter Agent INFO] *** - ACTUATOR AGENT SCHEDULE SUCCESS')

dr_level = self.vip.rpc.call('platform.actuator','get_point', dr_topic, point="signal_payload").get(timeout=15)
```

the `dr_topic` is `slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/33333`

Any ideas to try greatly appreciated...

Full traceback:

```
2021-06-15 14:36:27,597 (actuatoragent-1.0 403031) __main__ DEBUG: handle_get: slipstream_internal/slipstream_hq/33333
2021-06-15 14:36:27,598 (master_driveragent-4.0 403069) volttron.platform.vip.agent.subsystems.rpc ERROR: unhandled exception in JSON-RPC method 'get_point':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/volttron/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 158, in method
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/volttron/.volttron/agents/55fbfb56-beac-4e6d-a201-1ab17b11d42b/master_driveragent-4.0/master_driver/agent.py", line 448, in get_point
    return self.instances[path].get_point(point_name, **kwargs)
  File "/home/volttron/.volttron/agents/55fbfb56-beac-4e6d-a201-1ab17b11d42b/master_driveragent-4.0/master_driver/driver.py", line 341, in get_point
    return self.interface.get_point(point_name, **kwargs)
AttributeError: 'DriverAgent' object has no attribute 'interface'

2021-06-15 14:36:27,599 (actuatoragent-1.0 403031) volttron.platform.vip.agent.subsystems.rpc ERROR: unhandled exception in JSON-RPC method 'get_point':
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/volttron/volttron/platform/vip/agent/subsystems/rpc.py", line 158, in method
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/volttron/.volttron/agents/8f4ee1c0-74cb-4070-8a8c-57bf9bea8a71/actuatoragent-1.0/actuator/agent.py", line 897, in get_point
    return self.vip.rpc.call(self.driver_vip_identity, 'get_point', path,
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 305, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 335, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 305, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 305, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 323, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 303, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult._raise_exception
  File "/var/lib/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_compat.py", line 66, in reraise
    raise value
volttron.platform.jsonrpc.RemoteError: builtins.AttributeError("'DriverAgent' object has no attribute 'interface'")


2021-06-15 14:36:27,600 (setteroccvavagent-0.1 471606) volttron.platform.vip.agent.core ERROR: unhandled exception in periodic callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/volttron/volttron/platform/vip/agent/core.py", line 117, in _loop
    method(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/volttron/.volttron/agents/9c13ec66-7d7a-4f3d-a607-409a82e012ed/setteroccvavagent-0.1/setteroccvav/agent.py", line 252, in raise_setpoints_up
    dr_level = self.vip.rpc.call('platform.actuator','get_point', dr_topic, point="signal_payload").get(timeout=4)
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 305, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 335, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 305, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 305, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 323, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult.get
  File "src/gevent/event.py", line 303, in gevent._gevent_cevent.AsyncResult._raise_exception
  File "/var/lib/volttron/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gevent/_compat.py", line 66, in reraise
    raise value
volttron.platform.jsonrpc.RemoteError: volttron.platform.jsonrpc.RemoteError('builtins.AttributeError("\'DriverAgent\' object has no attribute \'interface\'")')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually what seemed to fix this is I restarted the actuator agent, bacnet proxy, and masteragent all at the same time. Was it maybe the master agent that needed a restart?

***UPDATE***

IF YOU HAD TO CHANGE SOMETHING IN THE CONFIG STORE FOR A DEVICE, for example make a BACnet point writeable instead of read ONLY; and something got fat fingered incorrectly this will ALSO CAUSE THE SAME ERROR! And also hard to troubleshoot.

For example on a live system if you had to modify something like this through vctl:

```
vctl config edit platform.driver registry_configs/1100.csv
```

And you create a syntax error with a fat finger this will also throw the same error!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
        driver = DriverAgent(self, contents, slot, self.driver_scrape_interval, topic,
                             group, self.group_offset_interval,
                             self.publish_depth_first_all,
                             self.publish_breadth_first_all,
                             self.publish_depth_first,
                             self.publish_breadth_first)
        gevent.spawn(driver.core.run)
        self.instances[topic] = driver
```

When the Platform Driver's configure method is called (which happens during a callback from the config store), the Platform Driver creates a driver instance with an interface class per the config that was passed.  If the config that was passed is somehow incorrect or improperly passed, then the Platform Driver will be unable to actually instantiate the driver, and therefore it will not be added to the "self.instances" dictionary (above).  When you make a call to the Platform Driver, you include a topic.  That path *MUST* match the key that maps to the driver instance value in the "self.instances" dictionary.

As such, I have a couple of spots to suggest investigating.  1) Re-load the configs into the config store and watch the VOLTTRON log file as you do so.  If you do not see a dictionary representation of the config file in the VOLTTRON log (while running in verbose logging mode) then you have likely given it an improperly formatted config.  2) Double check the topic you're using in your RPC calls. If the topic is not in the "self.instances" dictionary, it will throw an error as it's asking for a key that does not exist.

The configs you have posted above appear to me to be correct, so the topic in the RPC call or the commands used to store the configs appear to me to be the most likely culprits.

Comment: Thanks for all of your help and quick responses @jklarson always appreciated on my end